# Efficiency of this Newtown-Raphson implementation for Black Scholes implied volatility?

Tags: c++, quantitative-finance

I've implemented an algorithm for calculating the implied volatility (shown below), and was looking for feedback on how I could improve my code, whether it's speed, organization, etc. I'm very new to C++ so I'm looking to get in front of any bad habits.

Please assume the implementation for "bs_option_price_analytical" and "vega_bs" are optimally written. These are used in the first derivative calculation.

```
double newton_raphson_implied_vol(char type, double mkt_price, double S, double K, double T, double sigma0, double r, double q, double tol)
{
    // Initialize variables
    double bs_price_old{bs_option_price_analytical(type, S, K, T, sigma0, r, q)};
    double bs_mkt_diff{bs_price_old - mkt_price}; // To avoid repeated calculations in While condition
    double sigma_new{-bs_price_old/vega_bs(S, K, T, sigma0, r, q) + sigma0}; // First new value (to be updated iteratively later) 

    // Iterate using Newton-Raphson method
    while (abs(bs_mkt_diff/mkt_price) > tol)
    {
        bs_price_old = bs_option_price_analytical(type, S, K, T, sigma_new, r, q);
        bs_mkt_diff = bs_price_old - mkt_price;
        sigma_new = -bs_mkt_diff/vega_bs(S, K, T, sigma_new, r, q) + sigma_new;
    }

    return sigma_new;
}
```

Comment: If you have working code and are looking for a review then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask. Be sure to read through their help section to be sure you include everything required for your question to be on-topic.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for telling them to read through https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help. The posted this same exact post on Code Review, and there it has received 2 of the necessary 3 votes to close so far.